# How to generate index in the Eco model

Tags: mdriven

How to generate index in the Eco model, I need an extra search index on some table columns is it possible to ask model to generate them for me?
ON SQLServer

Answer (score 1):

The script generator only adds indices for primary and foreign keys. You must add additional attribute indices manually in the DB.
We had a wish to add this feature but to get good effect of indices one must include all the columns needed in a specific search - and the hints from a query optimizer helps you better.